# ¿Por qué no lee mi validación?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Al queres insertar un archivo .CSV quiero validar que no me repita algunos datos pero parece que no lee la validación. Si elimino el if y else me registra normalmente, pero quiero que cuando se repita el campo CMSID en el array en la BD, cancele todo el proceso y no se registre ni un dato. Que puedo hacer?

```
foreach ($contactList as $contactData) 
{   
    ///VALIDAR CMSID
    $verificar_cmsid ="SELECT * FROM User  WHERE CMSID='$contactData[3]'";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($verificar_cmsid);

    if (in_array($resultado, $contactData)) {
        echo "El cmsid no está en el array, procedemos a registrar";
        $conexion->query("INSERT INTO User 
                        (Name,
                         UserName,
                         Password,
                         CMSID,
                         Client,
                         Gang)
                         VALUES

                         ('{$contactData[0]}',
                          '{$contactData[1]}', 
                          '{$contactData[2]}',
                          '{$contactData[3]}',
                          '{$contactData[4]}',
                          '{$contactData[5]}' 
                           )

                         "); 
                         print_r($contactData[3]);
                         print_r($verificar_cmsid); 
    }else{
        echo "hay uno o mas CMSID repetidos en el array y BD, procedemos a abortar";
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

---

En caso de yo querer validar otro campo, como lo seria el UserName, para que no sea ni repetido el CMSID ni UserName (asi se llaman en la BD) y el campo de es $contactData[1]. Que podria hacer?

```
// insertar contactos
foreach ($contactList as $contactData) {    
    $verificar_cmsid = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as cuenta FROM User  WHERE CMSID = ?';
    $prep = $conexion->prepare($verificar_cmsid);
    $prep->execute([$contactData[3]]);
    $resultado = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    if($resultado['cuenta'] == 0) {
        $insertar = 'INSERT INTO User (Name, UserName, Password, CMSID, Client, Gang) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $prep = $conexion->prepare($insertar);
        $prep->execute($contactData);
        echo "REGISTRADO CORRECTAMENTE";
    } else {
        echo "OPERACION CANCELADA, VALIDE QUE LOS CAMPOS YA NO ESTEN REGISTRADOS EN LA BD";
        return false;
    }
}
```

LO ESTUVE REALIZANDO DE ESTE MODO Y ME ARROJA ESTE ERROR: Array to string conversion in

```
// insertar contactos
foreach ($contactList as $contactData) {    
    $verificar_cmsid = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as cuenta FROM User  WHERE CMSID = ? or UserName = ?';
    $prep = $conexion->prepare($verificar_cmsid);
    $prep->execute([$contactData[3],[$contactData[1] ]]);
    $resultado = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    if($resultado['cuenta'] == 0) {
        $insertar = 'INSERT INTO User (Name, UserName, Password, CMSID, Client, Gang) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $prep = $conexion->prepare($insertar);
        $prep->execute($contactData);
        echo "REGISTRADO CORRECTAMENTE";
    } else {
        echo "OPERACION CANCELADA, VALIDE QUE LOS CAMPOS YA NO ESTEN REGISTRADOS EN LA BD";
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué librería usas para conectar a base de datos, mysqli o PDO? `$resultado` no es un arreglo, porque solo ejecutaste la consulta, pero no verificas si devolvió alguna fila. Además, en lugar de `SELECT * FROM tabla` deberías contar con `SELECT COUNT() FROM tabla`

Comment: Hola, estoy usando PDO. El arreglo lo estoy importando desde un input type file, que me trae un archivo CSV. Selecciono el campo numero [3] que seria el CSMID y lo comparo con el CMSID de la BD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te mencioné en comentarios, en lugar de seleccionar todos los campos, solo necesitas [contar](https://www.anerbarrena.com/mysql-count-5979/) cuántas filas coinciden con la búsqueda y, ya que estás usando PDO, te recomiendo que solo realices [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) para reducir riesgo de ataques y errores.

Creo que la opción más fácil de entender es usando [marcadores (signos de cierre de interrogación)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php#example-1007) para cada valor que se vaya a remplazar al ejecutar la consulta.

Aparte, solo estás ejecutando la consulta, pero no la lees. En consultas preparadas debes usar [->fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) y es recomendable que devuelva un arreglo asociativo del estilo `nombre_de_campo => valor`, solo necesitas enviar como parámetro la constante `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

```
foreach ($contactList as $contactData) {    
    // VALIDAR CMSID usando consultas preparadas usando marcadores ?
    $verificar_cmsid = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as cuenta FROM User  WHERE CMSID = ?';
    // Preparar consulta
    $prep = $conexion->prepare($verificar_cmsid);
    // Ejecutar, agregando un arreglo con datos para cada marcador ?
    $prep->execute([$contactData[3]]);
    // Leer resultado de la consulta como arreglo asociativo
    $resultado = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    // Solo si el resultado de contar fue cero
    if($resultado['cuenta'] == 0) {
        echo "El cmsid no está en la tabla, procedemos a registrar";
        // Crear consulta con marcadores ?
        $insertar = 'INSERT INTO User (Name, UserName, Password, CMSID, Client, Gang) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        // Preparar consulta
        $prep = $conexion->prepare($insertar);
        // Si $contactData solo tiene 6 elementos, se usan directamente para ejecutar
        $prep->execute($contactData);
    } else {
        echo "Hay uno o mas CMSID repetidos en BD, procedemos a abortar";
        return false;
    }
}
```

### ¿Por qué usar consultas preparadas?

En este caso, el riesgo de ataques SQL es prácticamente nulo si tienes el control del contenido del archivo a importar, pero siempre hay riesgo de errores, por ejemplo, con tu consulta original:

```
$verificar_cmsid ="SELECT * FROM User  WHERE CMSID = '$contactData[3]'";
```

Supongamos que `$contactData[3]` puede contener un valor como `XYZ's01`, la consulta no se va a ejecutar, porque esa comilla "rompe" la cadena, quedando así:

```
SELECT * FROM User  WHERE CMSID = 'XYZ's01'
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo, veo muy difícil que en el campo CMSID pueda pasar, pero considera que sí es posible en otros campos como nombres personales o contraseñas.

Al usar consultas preparadas todos los valores son "escapados" para evitar estos errores y, de paso, también te ayudan a minimizar el riesgo de ataques SQL.

### Solución sin consultas preparadas

En caso de que no quieras usar consultas preparadas y solo corregir el error, debes leer el resultado de la consulta agregando `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` al final:

```
///VALIDAR CMSID contando filas en lugar de seleccionar todos los campos
$verificar_cmsid ="SELECT COUNT(*) as cuenta FROM User  WHERE CMSID='$contactData[3]'";
$resultado = $conexion->query($verificar_cmsid)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Solo si el resultado de contar fue cero
if($resultado['cuenta'] == 0) {
    echo "El cmsid no está en el array, procedemos a registrar";
    // Aquí realizas la inserción normalmente
```

Comment: Sinceramente eres el mejor! Llevaba casi una semana intentado corregir ese error, me estaba dando por vencido. Te agradezco. Saludos desde Colombia, muchas gracias!!!!!.

Comment: Bro, que pena molestarte. En caso de yo querer validar otro campo, como lo seria el UserName, para que no sea ni repetido el CMSID ni UserName (asi se llaman en la BD) y el campo de es $contactData[1]. Que podria hacer?

Comment: Agrega el otro campo en la consulta: `... WHERE campo1 = 'valor1' OR campo2 = 'valor2'`

Comment: Bro, me arroja este error: Array to string conversion in

Comment: Debe quedar así: `WHERE CMSID = '$contactData[3]' OR UserName = '$contactData[1]'`

Comment: Con consulta preparada debe ser un solo arreglo: `$prep->execute([$contactData[3], $contactData[1]]);`

Comment: Gracias bro. Disculpa la molestia. Me funciono.

Comment: @JohanyAndresGomez, no es molestia, todos estamos aquí para aprender y me alegra que te haya funcionado.